# async await not working with Timer

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a Presence monitor class which is used to detect users active/inactive status. That class has a timer in its Start method which called on application start:

```
public class PresenceMonitor
{
    private volatile bool _running;
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly TimeSpan _presenceCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);


    public PresenceMonitor()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Start the timer
        _timer = new Timer(_ =>
        {
            Check();
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _presenceCheckInterval);
    }

    private void Check()
    {
        if (_running)
        {
            return;
        }

        _running = true;

        // Dowork
    }
}
```

The "Check" method is fired after every one minute. That piece of code is working fine but now my "Do work" methods have become async await so I had to change this Presence Monitor class to something like this:

```
public class PresenceMonitor
{
    private volatile bool _running;
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly TimeSpan _presenceCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);


    public PresenceMonitor()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Start the timer
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (e) =>
        {
            await CheckAsync();
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _presenceCheckInterval);
    }

    private async Task CheckAsync()
    {
        if (_running)
        {
            return;
        }

        _running = true;

        // await DoworkAsync
    }
}
```

Unfortunately "CheckAsync" method now is getting fired once only instead of every minute. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here to call async await after regular intervals?

Is there any correct way to do the same?

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You could consider creating an event and handler to handle the timer ticks and then invoke your check.

```
public class PresenceMonitor {
    private volatile bool _running;
    private Timer timer;
    private readonly TimeSpan _presenceCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    public PresenceMonitor() {
        Tick += OnTick;
    }

    public void Start() {
        if (_running) {
            return; //already running
        }
        // Start the timer
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => {
            Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty);//rasie event
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _presenceCheckInterval);
    }

    private event EventHandler Tick = delegate { };
    private async void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        if (_running) {
            return;
        }
        _running = true;
        await DoworkAsync();
    }

    private Task DoworkAsync() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Having goose bumps to see this reply. Thanks for your effort on this. Let me check that

Comment: It should be "private async Task DoworkAsync(), Right?

Comment: @Raghav, Only if you are using `await` within that method. I do not know what the method looks like so it would depend on how it is implemented.

Comment: This is the minimal change but do note that errors from `async void` are not  observed. You should put a try/catch around the call to DoWorkAsync().

Comment: @HenkHolterman `async void` are allowed on event handlers. I do get your point though. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your requirements, you can get rid of timer and use asynchronous loop.
But you need make `Start` method asynchronous too

```
public class PresenceMonitor
{
    private volatile bool _running; // possible not needed "volatile" anymore
    private readonly int _presenceCheckInterval = 60000; // Milliseconds

    public PresenceMonitor()
    {
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        while (true) // may be use some "exit" logic
        {
           await CheckAsync();
           await Task.Delay(_presenceCheckInterval) 
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckAsync()
    {
        if (_running)
        {
            return;
        }

        _running = true;

        // await DoworkAsync
    }
}
```

Then you can start monitoring

```
var monitor = new PresenceMonitor();
await monitor.Start();
```

You can even start monitoring in synchronous way

```
var monitor = new PresenceMonitor();
monitor.Start(); // Will start monitoring
```

But approach above is "dangerous" in the way, that any exception thrown inside `CheckAsync` method will not be propagated. When you start using `async-await` be ready to "convert" whole application to support it.

Comment: You just moved the problem around. Now the call to Start() has become async, you don't know if/how that is solvable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman,  based on OP's sample after executing `Start` method, application should run `CheckAsync` every minute. My example will do exactly same thing in little bid more simply/readable/maintainable way. If OP starts using `async` in his application he will end up anyway with "problem" to make all methods of application "pipeline" `async`.

Comment: Yes, and that's why this is not complete without a call to Start(). Which the question didn't include either.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Sorry, I think answer is complete for current version of OP's question. Can you suggest improvements to the answer?